# Make workbook read only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is automatically updated by a VBA macro.

To get around the potential issue of a user having the workbook open in read-write when the macro tries to update it I am setting the attribute to read-only when the macro saves it, and then turning it off when it opens the book for editing.

```
SetAttr ThisWorkbook.Path & "\booktoupdate.xlsx", vbNormal

'Paste in some values

SetAttr ThisWorkbook.Path & "\booktoupdate.xlsx", vbReadOnly
```

However any user could go into the properties of the file and turn off read only.

Is there any way to protect the file so read-only can only be changed by VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will exactly suit your requirement: while saving workbook you can enable with password like below,

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\booktoupdate.xlsx", _
    WriteResPassword:="enter your password", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
```

when other user try to edit it will prompt for password and excel remains in read only mode

Comment: This won't prevent the file from been edited by another person!

Comment: @Pspl this will prevent because we are saving file with password and in readonly mode enabled, try this will work, if you cant get result then down vote.

Comment: @DvynResh This does appear to do what I want, however now when I try to open the file I get an error that the password I entered is incorrect. Before being displayed the password box, any ideas what could cause this? Just a weird bug?

Comment: Update: that issue only happens the first time I try to open the file. Following times work fine, also seems to work fine when another user tries to open it. So it's not a huge problem.

Comment: @EdwardHall glad its works for you, regarding that bug you can recheck the code which opens the workbook.

Comment: @DvynResh: I got from the question that OP wanted to prevent from other people to edit the file. This process allows another person to change everything and save the file (with another name, yet it's possible). Also, they could always delete the original file and rename their copy. That's what I got!